# запрос и получение данных с другого сервера

Tags: php, cron, openserver

Есть php скрипт, который посылает запрос с серверу и обрабатывает полученные данные. Проблема в том, что при запуске скрипта через cron, сервер возвращает `false`.

Скрипт обработчика:

```
<?php 


echo $r = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ': ' . rand(25,45) . "\n";
$path = __DIR__ . '/forcron1.txt';
file_put_contents($path, $r, FILE_APPEND);
//работает, записывает в файл тестовые данные

$rss = 'site.com/rss.xml';
$xmlstr = @file_get_contents($rss);
if($xmlstr===false)die('Error connect to RSS: '.$rss);
echo $r = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ': ' . rand(25,45) . "\n";
$path = __DIR__ . '/forcron2.txt';
file_put_contents($path, $r, FILE_APPEND);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$msg = false;
$notifies = false;
if($xml===false)die('Error parse RSS: '.$rss);
//тут не работает, ибо сервер возвращает false, дальше нет смысла разбирать скрипт

foreach($xml->channel->item as $item){  
    $date = new DateTime($item->pubDate);
    $datenow = new DateTime();
    $datenow->sub(new DateInterval('PT1M'));
    if ($date > $datenow) {
        $date = $date->format('d.m.Y H:i');
        $notifies[] = ['title' => $item->title, 'pubDate' => $date, 'link' => $item->link, 'category' => $item->category];  
    }   
}
echo $r = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ': ' . rand(25,45) . "\n";
$path = __DIR__ . '/forcron3.txt';
file_put_contents($path, $r, FILE_APPEND);

if ($notifies) {
    foreach ($notifies as $item) {
        $msg .= "<a href='{$item[link]}'>{$item[title]}</a>\r\nОпубликовано: {$item[pubDate]}\r\nКатегория: {$item[category]}\r\n\r\n";

    }
} else {
    $msg = "Нет новых проектов";
}
$msg = urlencode($msg);
$users = ['user1', 'user2'];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $link = "site.com/?msg=".$msg;
    $xmlstr = @file_get_contents($link);
}
```

Вопрос: почему невозможно получить данные через cron? Cron использую через openserver, следующая команда:

```
%progdir%\modules\php\%phpdriver%\php-win.exe -c %progdir%\userdata\temp\config\php.ini -q -f %sitedir%\reals2\index.php
```

Comment: что в логах крона?

Comment: $xmlstr = @file_get_contents($rss); возможно не получаете данные. Уберите подавление, посмотрите какая ошибка

Comment: Совет (может и не в тему): никогда не используйте подавление ошибок `@`. Код нужно писать так, чтобы даже с включенным отображением ошибок `ini_set("display_errors",1)` ошибок не было